# how to merge this? (First and Last Vertices)

Tags: screw-modifier

I have just an edge.

I added a screw modifier.
Then a solidify modifier.
then a simple deform modifier.

result:

[image]

But i have no idea, how can i merge this? or do i have to do that manually after applying?
Or can i somehow adjust this that it fits?

Comment: try the Weld modifier at the end, play with the value, it should merge the vertices

Comment: works! thank you!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the *Weld* modifier at the end of your modifier stack (or as Robin says, at a more accurate place in your stack), play with the threshold value, it should merge the vertices.

Answer (score 5):

Would recommend *Deform* before *Solidify*, so the *Weld* doesn't have to cover internal faces..

[image]

...leaving no defects in normals. (Also, for less experienced users, note the angle of *Bend* is a soft limit: it can be taken beyond 360 by typing in)